# Indicatif ou subjonctif dans la phrase citée dans les détails?

Tags: conjugaison, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, concordance-des-temps, reformulation

> Je ne vais pas te rendre la pareille sur le coup (retourner le compliment) de peur que tu penses que **je ne le fasse** que par politesse, c’est-à-dire sans égard à ce que je pense vraiment.

> Je ne vais pas te rendre la pareille sur le coup (retourner le compliment) de peur que tu penses que **je ne le fais** que par politesse, c’est-à-dire sans égard à ce que je pense vraiment.

Je suis conscient qu’il y a beaucoup de « que », alors si vous avez une façon plus jolie en tête de tourner cette phrase et qui permet de se passer de ces « que » consécutifs (3), n’hésitez pas à me la présenter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Je ne pense pas avoir jamais vu autre chose que l'indicatif dans ce style de tournure :

> *Je ne te l'avais pas dit, de peur que tu ne penses que c'est une insulte à ton égard et à celui de papa.* Tananarive Due, *La Rose noire*, 2000.

> *J'ai tardé à te le dire de peur que tu ne penses que je suis fou.* Stéphanie Nicot, *Anthologie du monstre*, 2017.

> *Mais de peur que tu ne penses que je te fais cette demande du bout des lèvres seulement, et que j'use de dissimulation, [...]* Vincent de Lérins, *Oeuvres de Vincent de Lérins et de St Eucher de Lyon*, 1834

> *Mais c'est assez, je n'ajouterai pas un mot de peur que tu ne penses que j'ai dérobé les tablettes du chassieux Crispinus.*, Horace traduit par J. B. Monfalcon, Oeuvres complètes - Livre premier, Satire II, 1834.

donc :

> Je ne vais pas te rendre la pareille sur le coup de peur que tu penses que je ne le **fais** que par politesse, c’est-à-dire sans égard à ce que je pense vraiment.

et pour simplifier un peu:

> Je ne vais pas te retourner le compliment, de peur que tu y voies plus politesse que sincérité.

Answer (score 0):

« [De peur que](https://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4238) » est une locution conjonctive pour laquelle le subjonctif est nécessaire, mais, évidemment, cela concerne le verbe « penser » et rien n'est dit à propos de « faire ». Comme il n'y a rien de fait et que l'action est que considérée seulement comme une possibilité, il me semble que le subjonctif est préférable (je ne trouve pas de référence).

Aussi une option, le conditionnel marque bien une action seulement envisagée.

- Je ne vais pas te rendre la pareille (retourner le compliment)  de peur que tu penses que je ne le ferais que par politesse, c’est-à-dire sans égard à ce que je pense vraiment.

*Formulation alternative (moins d'occurrences du mot « que »)*

- Je ne vais pas te rendre la pareille (retourner le compliment) de peur que tu le  reçoives  dans l'esprit d'un échange de politesses, c’est-à-dire formulé sans égard à ce que je pense vraiment.